# Jump on frame after FLV video finishes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flv

So I cant figure this out, i need when the FLV video finishes to jump back to the frame (1)?

```
stop();
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
videoPlayer.attachNetStream(ns);

var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.onMetaData = function(evt:Object):void {};
ns.client = listener;

ns.play("Tchibo_movie.flv");

videoPlayer.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completefunc);
function completefunc(e)
{
    trace("completed");
    gotoAndPlay (1);

}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you trying to go back to the first frame of the flv or swf timeline?

Comment: Is 'completed' being traced? If not this might be due to the flashplayer version you are targeting.

Comment: no ! I only trace this to see if the scripts get the end of the video, but i don't get it traced, so the problem is that i can't catch the end of the flv video.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen `NetStream` for `NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS`.

```
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, handleStreamStatus);
function handleStreamStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void{ 
    if(e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Complete"){               
        trace('completed');
    }
}
```